# Error: Unknown Puppet subcommand 'module'

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, puppet

It seems there is a problem with `puppet` on `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS` as its missing the module subcommand as follows:

```
Installed puppet in version 2.7.11

$ puppet module install rafaelfc-pear
Installing rafaelfc-pear puppet module...
Error: Unknown Puppet subcommand 'module'
See 'puppet help' for help on available puppet subcommands

$ puppet module install puppetlabs-apache
Installing puppetlabs-apache puppet module...
Error: Unknown Puppet subcommand 'module'
See 'puppet help' for help on available puppet subcommands

$ puppet module 
Error: Unknown Puppet subcommand 'module'
See 'puppet help' for help on available puppet subcommands

$ puppet help module
err: Could not find Puppet Face :module
err: Try 'puppet help help help' for usage

$ puppet module 
err: 'module' has no default action.  See `puppet help module`.

$ puppet help module
USAGE: puppet module
```

With `sudo`, its the same thing.

Related: http://www.wiredpea.com/article/puppet-modules-and-ubuntu-1204

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The puppet module face has been released in [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software) puppet in 2.7.14.
It would have been in 2.7.13, but 2.7.13 got bumped to 2.7.14 by the recent security release.

This is according to: [Bug #13937 - puppet 2.7.13 RPM missing "puppet module" face.](https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/13937)

So you may try to re-install your puppet by the recent version:

```
$ curl -O https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-precise.deb && sudo dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-precise.deb # dpkg >= 1.17.7 # curl -o- https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-precise.deb | sudo dpkg --install - 
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install puppet
```

Read more: [Installing Puppet: Debian and Ubuntu](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/install_debian_ubuntu.html)

Or as workaround, you can try:

```
gem install puppet-module # Prefix with sudo if necessary.
```

See: [Error: Unknown Puppet subcommand 'module'](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/puppet/+question/213144)

Answer (score 2):

Puppet 2.7.x is a very old version.

You should install a more recent version (3.7 at the time of this writing)

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties
cd /tmp
wget http://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-precise.deb
sudo dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-precise.deb
apt-get update 
apt-get install -y puppet-common #masterless puppet
apt-get install -y puppet        #masterful puppet
```

Answer (score 1):

I only used Puppet Enterprise. But I believe usually you should use sudo for installing modules. Also, make sure you're running this stuff on the master, not on an agent.